# Media Player Classic doesn't play videos with over long names when using "drag and drop" method

Tags: video, media-player-classic

When I double click on an over long name file it played as expected but when I drag and drop the same file onto a MPC window it didn't play and it shows "File not found".

Is there a solution for this problem other than using shorter names?

Comment: There is no solution that does not imply modifying the source code of MPC. I would suggest to give [VLC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Reading some of the source code I've came up with this lines

```
for (UINT iFile = 0; iFile < nFiles; iFile++) {
    CString fn;
    fn.ReleaseBuffer(::DragQueryFile(hDrop, iFile, fn.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), MAX_PATH));
    slFiles.AddTail(fn);
}
```

MAX_PATH if it's from standard Windows API and it's limit is 260 chars long, so that's the limit for drag and drop, unless you modify it. From the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file):

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character.